# Unable to remove elements from form Design List

Tags: forms, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I've made a form in AX 2012 and duplicated, renamed and deleted countless elements in the Form Design.

I now have many elements in my Design List that are no longer in my form's design (CopyOfGrid2_Payment, CopyOfGrid2_SalesId ect..), but I am unable to remove/delete them: no right click delete or delete key on the keyboard.

Any ideas how I can get rid of elements in my Design list that are not part of the Design? Any ideas why I am not able to delete these elements?

Comment: I guess you have tried "Restore"?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I've done that. I have been working on this form for two weeks, and restore regularly.

Comment: Are the fields included in a field group (and the group included in the form)?

Comment: Yes! Silly me.. They are part of a field group and they are actually part of the form, so I no longer want to delete them. Since I no longer want to delete then, you solved my problem. Just for the future, are elements that are part of a field group "undeletable" from the Design List?

Comment: Yes, by design. You can hide them of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields are included in a field group and the group included in the form.